# Looking for JavaScript RSA Lib 2048bits

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am looking for a RSA JavaScript Library, to encode messages with 2048bits. As parameters I have the mod and exp.

Any suggestions?

http://ohdave.com/rsa/ is very very slow ...

Basically I just want to have this few lines from Java working in Javascript

```
final BigInteger mod = new BigInteger("24197023742877246512461757490880309237958027777725822732692302307843826065437540673020676917825610058185629137689258656193849850440743940874819183871269999253944042385049224164120254090375365376709174303924454412229678909482117353022491122094962851832239328803282732638247320612677183304158816764694319471052845912232446151620358194723026156979044025875290500632104466233205010763939741450753158843137124689955872516700870629048046288220560359265881151146540009255370538519849429733539445188287525631514301030537792870463475023632636041223554887103782248303563304443978457914857475908030765497628649778466179256664651");
final BigInteger exp = new BigInteger("23139601584407978251606203018538255044792155193454239408670287967705206387218929560404426270212009386707782396911651551942218161903546775202519839339061975116993987646645254223383869945314788199864108536397108982371342391228965940857509286281911085537664761189681228964354095011341945911798610297903277296935707197643500842487686588664503922028182768389581098745054341591421596765805353910748418759970760060122504351418627635922030816083629993980577802392293471805191132307965316768557540634864009685313523238948086384123273996765014668141916815067709883071065927377949234999779835469873986654327727461324511444935481");

Key key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new RSAPrivateKeySpec(mod, exp));

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

byte[] signature = cipher.doFinal(sha1);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(signature));
```

Comment: Doing quick search on stackoverflow for "javascript cryptography" and similar searches reveals a handful of answers, partially explaining why the idea is completely flawed, and partially referencing various solutions including Javascript libraries.

Comment: In particular see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176574/javascript-cryptography-library-to-sign-form-data-in-browser

Comment: Also see http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: Performance wise (never minding the security) you are a lot better off using Elliptic Curve Cryptography instead of RSA if you want to perform *signing* operations, especially for key sizes that provide a high security margin.

Comment: That should be signing or decryption purposes of course. Note that ECC operations do require a source of secure random. The same goes for asymmetric encryption of course.

Comment: I don't like the idea of crypting in JavaScript either, but I have to do it ... @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp like I said ohdave is too slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a Java Applet from Javascript and do the crypto there. The user will likely be prompted by the browser to give the applet/plugin permission to run. Take a look at [cryptoapplet](http://tomas.styblo.name/cryptoapplet/index.html) for an example.